# firebase storage, pictures is readable also in private mode

Tags: firebase-security, firebase-storage

i have a problem with the firebase storage rules, i saved a picture in firebase storage and, if i set the read mode in false is equally possible to see the image. after i save my image in the storage i change my storage rules with this simple code

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/mybucketaddress/o {
    match /{allImages=**}{
       allow write, read: if false
    }    
  }
}
```

if i put the picture address in the browser the picture is still visible (also into my app, not only in browser), how i fix this problem?

Comment: Keep in mind that download URLs are not following this security model. They are always publicly accessible, unless you revoke them. So if you show the image in your app by downloading from the download URL, setting the rules to not allow public access won't make a difference: you'll need to revoke the URL.

Comment: is possible to revoke the URL by client code? (javascript). i want to make visible a photo only if occur certain events. i thinks is possibile by the revoke and the invoke of the download URL

Comment: There is no API to revoke access tokens/download URLs at the moment. If you need that kind of control, it's probably better to not generate a download URL and control access purely through the security rules.

Comment: at first time i put only the storage file address but i see that in this mode the image is not visible. is neccessary to download it by the URL